# deselect tag with 'select2'

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Hi I new with java script.

I try to save in array all selected tags, its work ok, but when I press 'x' on tag I want then delete from this array, how can I do this?

```
 $( "#select2-2" ).change(function() {
     $( "#select2-2 option:selected" ).each(function() {
         strArr[i] = $( this ).text();
         i++;
     });
 }).trigger("change");
```

**My html code:**

```
<select id="select2-2" class="form-control" multiple>
   <option>tag1</option>
   <option>tag2</option>
   <option>tag3</option>
   <option>tag4</option>
   <option>tag5</option>
</select>
```

**More explain about Select-2:**

https://select2.github.io/

select-2 create tags when you select option from select list, like this:

[tag3 x][tag2 x][tag4 x]

When I select option from select list, I get it like visual tag.. so I save the tags in array. But when I press 'x' I want remove this tag from my array.

Any idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Add a remove button, then link it to this bit of code:
    $('#select2-2').find(':selected').remove();
Which will remove all selected options within select2-2

```js
var strArr = [];

$("#select2-2").change(function () {
     var i = 0;
     $("#select2-2 option:selected").each(function () {
         strArr[i] = $(this).text();
         i++;
     });
 }).trigger("change");

$('#remove').click(function(){
    $('#select2-2').find(':selected').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select2-2" class="form-control" multiple>
   <option>tag 1</option>
   <option>tag 2</option>
   <option>tag 3</option>
   <option>tag 4</option>
   <option>tag 5</option>
</select><br>
<button id="remove" type="button">Remove</button>
```

Comment: I add more details about select-2 and what I want to do.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add jQuery! only tested it on jfiddle. fixed.